# Which is correct, 'self-employed' or 'self employed'?

Tags: orthography, hyphenation, modifiers

In the sentence

> Self-employed [or *Self employed*] farmer Belle Vue has lived in the state of Washington all her life.

should there be a hyphen between *Self* and *employed*?

Comment: Neither: spelling is not grammar.

Comment: Since *self-employed* is a unit, treat it as such by connecting the two elements with a hyphen. Without a hyphen, *self* floats about without an anchor, so to speak, since the element to which it is conceptually attached has not been made orthographically clear.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the context. If you are using it as an adjective, you want to hyphenate it.

> He is a self-employed gardener.

On the other hand, if you use it as a two-word noun, you do not hyphenate.

> He is self employed, and works as a gardener.

Comment: I'm not sure how the second example is a two-word noun.  In fact, can "self-employed" be a noun?  Wouldn't it be "self employment" in that case?  Or "being self employed?"

Answer (score 0):

According to the Chicago Manual of Style's [guide to hyphen use](http://www.chicagomanualofstyle.org/16/images/ch07_tab01.pdf), it should be **self-employed**. The guide says to hyphenate after the prefix *self* unless it is preceded by *un* or followed by a suffix.